# 'An NSManagedObject of class 'className' must have a valid NSEntityDescription.' error

Tags: swift, core-data

I've created simple entity 'CDWorkout' with one attribute 'name' inside CDModel.xcdatamodeld. Name of container in AppDelegate is also 'CDModel'. Class Codegen for 'CDWorkout' is Category/Extension. Here is code for CDWorkout class:

```
class CDWorkout: NSManagedObject {

    class func createWorkout(workoutInfo : Workout, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> CDWorkout{
        let workout = CDWorkout(context: context)
        workout.name = "anyName"
        return workout
    }
}
```

the createWorkout function is called from another viewController with context argument as `container.viewContext` but it immediately crashes with message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An NSManagedObject of class 'Workout_Generator.CDWorkout' must have a valid NSEntityDescription.'

What did i forget about?

Comment: If us building SPM then Class Module set to empty

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The issue I had was that I needed to have the *Class Module* set to *Current Product Module* for my *CDWorkout* Entity.

In Xcode 10 there is a drop down in the Class section of the Data Model Inspector.

Comment: For those looking for this, in Xcode 10 it is a drop down in the Class section of the Data Model Inspector.  (Select your xcdatamodeld file)

Answer (score 36):

I had a silly minor issue that resulted in the same error. I was initializing NSPersistentContainer with the incorrect name.

It should have the same name as the source file with the extension *.xcdatamodeld*. e.g. *modelFileName.xcdatamodelId*

```
let persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "modelFileName")
```

Answer (score 16):

In my case the same problem was in @objc modifier in auto-generated header of data-class

```
@objc(CachedMovie)
public class CachedMovie: NSManagedObject {
```

I just removed `@objc(CachedMovie)` and it began to work

Comment: Yes it is true, better do not ask why

Comment: It does not allow me to remove the @objc annotation from the auto generated file..

Answer (score 11):

I came across this same error message when trying to insert/add a managed object from an extension (SiriKit). It seems to have been an issue with the namespace of the extension not matching the `.xcdatamodeld` file, because I was creating the entity description using `MyClass.entity()`.

The combination that worked for me was:

- `@objc(MyClass)` at the top of each `NSManagedObject` subclass
- Entities in the data model use the default "Global namespace", not "Current Product Module"
- Create the entity description using `let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "MyClass", in: context)!`

Comment: I'm being a bit dense here - for my model I only have one option - blank and "Current Product Module" - is blank the "Global namespace" you reference?

Also for the entity description - how does that create the entity description? Do I just add that code after creating an instance of my managed object? I.E. after this code? var newSavedModel = SomeEntity(context: managedContext)

Comment: @TheJeff Sorry, but I'm not entirely sure, it's been a couple years since I touched this sort of thing. I would guess that blank is the same as "Global namespace". The entity description I create above should be passed into the initializer for `NSManagedObject(entity:insertInto:)` as discussed [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506357-init).

Answer (score 11):

In `AppDelegate` check persistent container name.

```swift
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoreData")
```

If you trying to reach nonexistent `Core Data`, that may manifest as this error.

Name should be exact same as `.xcdatamodeld` object in navigation menu.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using coreData from a static library make sure you specify the module aswell

[image]

This gives you the correct entity access `MyStaticLibrary.MyManagedObject`

So if your receiving warnings with this dot notation, its not looking in your module

Answer (score 6):

One way this could happen is by trying to rename your entities. Make sure that these are the same!

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this is the problem.. Just not on the object I was looking for.. Check this on correct object. If you have EventDay and EventTime, try to to permute the object you are investigating in Core Data model..

Comment: Spared me some research time, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I've got the same issue. In my case I used CoreData initialised and managed in framework wich I integrated with main app via **SPM**.

### Solution

First, in the framework provide module name for entity by hand, by following steps:

1. open .xcdatamodel,
2. select Entity which you want to edit,
3. open **Data Model Inspector** (the 4th panel in right sidebar),
4. at section **Class** element Module by default presents **Current Product Module** -- enter here your Module name

Repeat these steps for each entity.

Second, in the framework override `description` for each NSManagedObject you use in project, f.ex. you have:

```
public class Person: NSManagedObject {

}
```

override there description with String without module name, like:

```
public class Person: NSManagedObject {

    public override var description: String {
        return "Person"
    }
}
```

Code presented above will help if you use convenience initialiser for Person (like `Person(context: Context)`) which uses `description` to specify `Person.entity()`.

Comment: For those reading this answer, SPM is Swift Package Manager. I have tried this and worked like a charm without the need of the description code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I forgot to add @objc(Reminder) in this below example. I wrote the NSManagedObject class programmatically.

```
@objc(Reminder)
public class Reminder: NSManagedObject {


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue using Swift Package Manager to import a Swift Package that had a model file included as a resource.  In my case setting the Module of my entity to `Current Production Module` produced an incorrect value in the model file.  When I used the debugger to print the model after loading the persistent container the fully qualified class name was something like `Module_Module.Class` instead of the expected `Module.Class`.  I had to manually type the module name instead of using `Current Production Module` to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

[image]in your file modeldataClass 
probably name of Class is incorrect cause before you change name something in your name class

Answer (score 1):

The mistake I made was to change the name of the entity and the generated "NSManagedObject Subclass" and not updating the name of the class. How to fix:

- open .xcdatamodeld
- click on the entity
- open the right panel
- Go to Data Model Inspector
- Change the name of the Class text field

Answer (score 1):

What fixed it for me was that I had an empty space in the name and didn't notice because of a line break. Removing it fixed the problem..

It was:

```
container = `NSPersistentContainer(name: "ContainerName ")`
```

Instead of:

```
container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "ContainerName")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue in CoreData stack with `NSManagedObjectModel` made from `Swift` code. The issue was in **wrong value** for `NSEntityDescription.managedObjectClassName` attribute. The `Swift module` prefix was missed.

Correct setup:

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription()
entity.name = PostEntity.entityName // `PostEntity`
entity.managedObjectClassName = PostEntity.entityClassName // `MyFrameworkName.PostEntity`
entity.properties = [....]
```

Where: `entityName` and `entityClassName` defined like this.

```
extension NSManagedObject {

    public static var entityName: String {
        let className = NSStringFromClass(self) // As alternative can be used `self.description()` or `String(describing: self)`
        let entityName = className.components(separatedBy: ".").last!
        return entityName
    }

    public static var entityClassName: String {
        let className = NSStringFromClass(self)
        return className
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying out adding CoreData to existing project and I renamed things a lot. I ended up with multiple .xcdatamodeld without knowing it. The solution was removing .xcdatamodeld and generated NSManagerObject and recreating it again.

Answer (score 0):

it easy to answer to this question. without removed

```
@objc(Workout)
```

the solution is on documentary [Core Data Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH30-SW1) on "**Entity Name and Class Name**".
here in your Xcode before doing (**Editor** -> **Create NSManagedObject SubClass**)
must change your class Name of Entities to add "MO", CoreData can differentiate between class Name and Entitie Name. and the

```
@objc(Workout)
```

will not be created, give us this one:

```
class CDWorkoutMO: NSManagedObject {

 class func createWorkout(workoutInfo : Workout, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> CDWorkoutMO {
    let workout = CDWorkoutMO(context: context)
    workout.name = "anyName"
    return workout
}
}
```

[like I do on my Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsOp0.png)

Answer (score 0):

For SwiftUI you need to also update this method from SceneDelegate:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    //This gets the context from AppDelegate and sets is as moc environment variable
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let contentView = ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had my Core Data model inside a Swift Package and had to follow [this](https://betterprogramming.pub/use-coredata-from-an-spm-package-e82c465d5d02) amazing guide and finally this is what did it:

I opened the model and selected the entity and in the right panel I selected the `Data Model Inspector` and in the Class panel, I manually entered the Module’s name i.e. the Swift Package name.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked,

Adding

@objc('YourEntityClassName')

above the class declaration in 'YourEntityClassName+CoreDataClass' file.

Note: I am using this in an SPM package.