# Why iOS app is throwing error as 'An NSManagedObject of class 'MYOWEB.SearchHistory' must have a valid NSEntityDescription.' in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I am using core data to save the data I have defined my entity as well but when I m calling my saveData function the app is crashing and throwing error as: **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An NSManagedObject of class 'MYOWEB.SearchHistory' must have a valid NSEntityDescription.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**

```
func saveData(name: String) {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let newItem = SearchHistory(context: context)
    newItem.name = name
    newItem.created_at = Date()
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        let nserror = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

my entity
[image]

SubClass Files

```
//
//  SearchHistory+CoreDataClass.swift
//  MYOWEB
//
//  Created by developer on 7/26/21.
//
//

import Foundation
import CoreData


public class SearchHistory: NSManagedObject {

}


//
//  SearchHistory+CoreDataProperties.swift
//  MYOWEB
//
//  Created by developer on 7/26/21.
//
//

import Foundation
import CoreData


extension SearchHistory {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<SearchHistory> {
        return NSFetchRequest<SearchHistory>(entityName: "SearchHistory")
    }

    @NSManaged public var created_at: Date?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?

}
```

Comment: Have you checked out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45434556/an-nsmanagedobject-of-class-classname-must-have-a-valid-nsentitydescription?

Answer (score 0):

oops! there was a little silly mistake as given the incorrect container name in appDelegate

```
`let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyoWeb_iOS")`
```

it working by replacing the above code

```
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MYOWEB")
```